# Spelling suggestions for MultiAutoCompleteTextView in Android?

Tags: android, autosuggest, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to bring up spelling suggestions for words when the user is typing in a MultiAutoCompleteTextView widget, like how Android will give you word suggestions as you type in their messaging app. I've set android:inputType="textAutoCorrect" but there are still no spelling suggestions appearing. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried implementing a solution from these recent findings yet, but the constant textAutoCorrect under http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType may prove useful. Also, look into the Android Spelling Checker framework here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html.

Answer (score 0):

here's my solution

```
edit.setRawInputType(edit.getInputType() & ~EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE);
```

this shows me words at the top of the [google] keyboard as I type just like in a normal EditText

and my custom Tokeniser and Adapter still show me stuff!